# AWS S3 large file reverse proxying with golang's http.ResponseWriter

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have a request handler named `Download` which I want to access a large file from Amazon S3 and push it to the user's browser. My goals are:

- To record some request information before granting the user access to the file
- To not buffer the file into memory too much. Files may become too large.

Here is what I've explored so far:

```
func Download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    sess := session.New(&aws.Config{
        Region:             aws.String("eu-west-1"),
        Endpoint:           aws.String("s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"),
        S3ForcePathStyle:   aws.Bool(true),
        Credentials:        cred,
    })

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)
    // I can't write directly into the ResponseWriter. It doesn't implement WriteAt. 
    // Besides, it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.
    _, err := downloader.Download(w, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET),
        Key: aws.String(filename),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(4, err.Error())
        return
    }

}
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a better approach (given the goals I'm trying to achieve).

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: I think what happens is that it uses parallel connections to download the file, which is why you need a WriterAt interface (much like in a torrent file). This shouldn't be that hard to implement.  If you need sequential read/write, try this other library for s3: https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/s3/s3.go#L188

Comment: The s3manager.Downloader is specially for downloading to a file with parallel connections. If you want to stream the file without buffering it locally, don't use the s3manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the file is potentially large, you don't want it to go trough your own server.
The best approach (in my opinion) is to have the user download it directly from S3.

You can do this by generating a ***presigned url***:

```
func Download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ...

    sess := session.New(&aws.Config{
        Region:             aws.String("eu-west-1"),
        Endpoint:           aws.String("s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"),
        S3ForcePathStyle:   aws.Bool(true),
        Credentials:        cred,
    })

    s3svc := s3.New(sess)
    req, _ := s3svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET),
        Key: aws.String(filename),
    })

    url, err := req.Presign(5 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}
```

The presigned url is only valid for a limited time (5 minutes in this example, adjust to your needs) and takes the user directly to S3. No need to worry about downloads anymore!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It's my first time working with the s3 service. I didn't know they provided such functionality. Thank you :-)

Comment: Suggest not adding the "Endpoint" parameter to the config unless you really need to. The Endpoint will automatically be built by the SDK as needed based on the "Region" and service.

Answer (score 13):

If you ***do*** want to stream the file through your service (rather than download directly as recommended in the accepted answer) -

```
import (
    ...

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func StreamDownloadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    sess, awsSessErr := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("eu-west-1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("my-aws-id", "my-aws-secret", ""),
    })
    if awsSessErr != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error creating aws session %s", awsSessErr.Error()), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    result, err := s3.New(sess).GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("my-bucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("my-file-id"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error getting file from s3 %s", err.Error()), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "my-file.csv"))
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-store")

    bytesWritten, copyErr := io.Copy(w, result.Body)
    if copyErr != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error copying file to the http response %s", copyErr.Error()), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Download of \"%s\" complete. Wrote %s bytes", "my-file.csv", strconv.FormatInt(bytesWritten, 10))
}
```